# Disable WordPress from adding <p> tags

Tags: wordpress

All I've got is the following little snippet of code:

```
<select size="1" name="EventHour<?php echo $i; ?>"> 
    <option>1</option> 
    <option>2</option> 
    <option>3</option> 
    <option>4</option> 
    <option>5</option> 
    <option>6</option> 
    <option>7</option> 
    <option>8</option> 
    <option>9</option> 
    <option>10</option> 
    <option>11</option> 
    <option>12</option> 
  </select> 
  : <!-- note this character -->
  <select size="1" name="EventMinute<?php echo $i; ?>"> 
    <option>00</option> 
    <option>05</option> 
    <option>10</option> 
    <option>15</option> 
    <option>20</option> 
    <option>25</option> 
    <option>30</option> 
    <option>35</option> 
    <option>40</option> 
    <option>45</option> 
    <option>50</option> 
    <option>55</option> 
  </select>
```

The should output fine. However, WordPress adds a p-tag around both of my select-elements as well as around the ":"-character. This makes them all end up on different rows.

I've installed and activated the WordPress plugin "Disable Visual Editor WYSIWYG" on this page without any success. Any other ideas what I can do to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Use this:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

in your `functions.php`

Here's the complete answer: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop#Disabling_the_filter

Comment: +1 for the link to the codex which provides a link to a plugin that lets you do this on individual pages with ease.

Answer (score 10):

Wordpress modifies and cleans your entered HTML both in the editor and at output.

Use this plugin to get unmodified markup into your posts:

https://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/raw-html/

Comment: I tried your suggestion ignoring readability for now and it still adds the <p> tag for some reason.

Comment: OK, I thoughtI had understood the process better... Can't get it to work properly, either. Maybe have a look at this plugin: https://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/raw-html/

Comment: I see. I modified the answer, because my initial explanation was actually wrong.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Search for "Raw HTML" in the Plugin Installer and then surround whatever html you want to remain pure with [raw][/raw].  This has been driving me nuts for years and finally I can get around it.  Thanks @pixelistik

Comment: "Cleans" is a strong word here.  Inserting p tags where I added none is the opposite of cleaning.

Answer (score 5):

```
<!-- wp:html -->

You can insert your code between these tags.

<!-- /wp:html -->
```

Tested on 5.6.2 WordPress

Comment: This also worked for me on WordPress 5.3.1.  @yayami-omate can you or anyone else point to some documentation about this trick?  Our site is still using the classic editor so I was surprised to see it work in that context (as opposed to the Gutenberg block editor).

Comment: This worked for me on WordPress 6.1.1. However, it took awhile because I made a stupid mistake. I had not noticed the requirement to have the slash in the closing tag. Without the slash, the content duplicated itself. For me, the best solution ended up being to only include the opening instruction as the first line in the editor (no closing). Also note, including wp:html generated pages that passes w3.org's HTML validation. Previously, I had stray  `p` tags errors.

Comment: This is the most useful answer for those of us with wordpress sites that have tons of content already and we don't have the time to go back and make sure every page looks good after doing `the_content` and `the_expert` filters. Wish I could double upvote this answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try this in your functions.php

```
<?php remove_filter ('the_content', 'wpautop'); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, still get the same result though.

Comment: @user1048676 Have you tried this plugin (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ps-disable-auto-formatting/)?

Comment: I just tried to install this plugin and still get the same issue.

Comment: Wordpress will not clean up the inserted <p> tags that it already has entered you have to clean them out, but they will not come back afterwards.

Comment: @mahatmanich Interesting. How do you "clean up" already inserted p tags? Especially when they do not even show up in the text editor? If you know how to get at that (a "meta text editor"?) it would be especially helpful information!

Answer (score 2):

You can minify your code. Wordpress won't destroy code if everything is on one line.

I do that when I want to put `<style>` or `<script>` tags inside certain posts.

Comment: Tried that, still screws with your code, added `p` and `br` at random places.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'm doing it manually for the page:

Result that **shows** extra `p` tags:

```
 <p><?php if($description){ echo $description; } ?></p> 
 <p><?php if($description){ echo wpautop($description); } ?></p>
```

Result that **removes** extra `p` tags:

```
 <?php if($description){ echo wpautop($description); } ?>
```

> Note, I removed the `p` tags around the `echo`, then added `wpautop` to the `echo`.

**End Result:**

```
<p>description content</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the post is custom post type, you can add meta box with [add_meta_box](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/) and there you can initialize your own editor with [wp_editor](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor) which can be customized. For example you can pass settings to the tinymce like 'force_p_newslines' and 'forced_root_block'

Answer (score 0):

At least with contact-form-7 I had some success using a html-minifier to prevent those pesky p-tags. Came here because I googled if others also find this as frustrating as I do.

If you still have problem after code minifire then use just convert your tag to `div` where `p` tag is automatically add.

Answer (score 0):

if anybody else is having this problem and can't or doesn't want to install another plugin, or again can't or doesn't want to have to edit their functions.php file, you can also do this!

My original code:

```
your original code

that worked wonderfully..

and then wordpress happened
```

My code with the workaround:

```
your original code
//
that worked wonderfully..
//
and then wordpress happened
```

So long as I make sure to not have any empty lines in my code this seems to be a workaround for me at least.  I'm wondering if the `:` wasn't enough to trick it not to add a p tag, but I'm coding in javascript and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround:
Put your select inside a `<div>` tag, without any whitespace chars between them. So Instead of :

```
<select ...>
</select>

<select ...>
</select>
```

You write this:

```
<div><select ...>
</select></div>

<div><select ...>
</select></div>
```

I've had the same problem with `<a>` elements, and this solved for me.