# Wordpress automatically adding paragraph

Tags: css, wordpress

So I am working on making a child theme of the "twenty fifteen" theme.

So far I have made custom post types with custom fields. It is imperative that I use custom fields for adding Soundcloud embedds. I have used the "Advanced Custom Fieds" plugin to do so.

Now, the problem I have is that whenever I use the custom field to add a soundcloud widget (just by pasting the link) it seems that the WYSIWYG Editor is adding the link inside a paragraph like this

```
<p>https://soundcloud.com/skitofficial/skit-ghost-dog</p>
```

This causes (I think) a white line (a new paragraph) to appear below the Soundcloud widget.
[image]

As you can see in the picture below, if I open the code view of the WYSIWYG I can spot the paragraph lines being added around the link.
[image]

So all in all, the main problem for me here is the white space below the soundcloud widget. Perhaps it does not have to do anything with the paragraph tag, but either way I the space below the widget looks bad, unprofessional and I need to remove it somehow. Now you may say "why don't you just remove those paragraph tags?" and that is the problem, even if I remove them, they are added automatically.

So, any suggestions would be very appreciated. I have worked my head on this for three days without any progress.

Edit: this question is old and I do not have the site anymore.

Comment: Have you disabled `wpautop`?

Comment: Could you just write a style for the `<p>` tags on that page? `.SoundcloudEmbedd p { margin: 0; }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable Wordpress from adding <p> tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248628/disable-wordpress-from-adding-p-tags)

Comment: You could just remove the <p> tags from the code editor for that specific piece of content or change them to <span> tags. Disabling <p> tags site wide might not be the best solution.

Comment: @JamesIves WP WYSIWYG adds `<p>` tags for some live breaks automatically.  If the issue it not due to erroneous whitespace after the content, your prpposed solution may not produce the desired result.

Comment: zgood's suggestion helps a lot. Adding margin: 0; removes the white space So now I have: .SoundcloudEmbedd p{margin: 0;} The problem now is how I can make the widget responsive. In other words how the widget can resize according to the screen size while keeping a 1:1 aspect ratio.

Comment: @Arete, that's a different question entirely. Please select an answer and ask a new question if you have one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just add this style to a global stylesheet:

`.SoundcloudEmbedd p { margin: 0; }`

seems safe

Comment: This seems like the best solution here. Although I am not quite sure how I can make the widget "responsive" now. I want it to adjust according to the screen size, keeping an aspect ratio of 1:1.

Comment: @Arete To keep the aspect ratio you want you could use the padding-top trick descibed [here](http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html). You would basically extend the style you just created. Maybe something like this: `.SoundcloudEmbedd p:before { content: ""; display: block; padding-top: 100%; }` Read the article I linked to get an explanation of what's going on

Comment: I didn't fully understand the tutorial you posted. I tried different methods without any luck. Also the code you posted does not make the widget responsive. I am now advised to create a new question regarding this, but I fear that doing so will create confusion (because now I need the style to have margin: 0;).

Comment: @Arete Ya I would make a new question, just mention in your new question the style you added to remove the margin

Comment: This might work for the OP's specific case, but it is only a superficial cosmetic fix. It does nothing to solve `autop` breaking included files that contain code. For example, in a page where I use `phpcode` to include a JavaScript or PHP file, WordPress automatically inserts paragraph tags at newlines, which creates syntax errors and breaks the code. Hiding paragraphs with CSS fixes nothing. This only treats the symptom; it doesn't cure the disease.

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress WYSIWYG pops in `<p>` tags.  If you're not careful, it will `<p>` all over your content.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop

Pop this into your `functions.php`

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
```

**EDIT**

If you're using ACF, the text area field type has an option for whether or not to add the `<p>` tags.  As mevius suggests, depending on your use case, you may want to consider using the URL field type.

OR, you can use this when calling the field in your theme.

```
the_field('wysiwyg_field', false, false);
```

Comment: `If you're not careful, it will <p> all over your content.` bahaha, thanks for the laugh. Keep in mind, removing `wpautop` like this will remove it *everywhere*, not just for those meta values.

Comment: This could be dangerous I would think. Don't you want `<p>` tags around most content?

Comment: @Plummer, if you keep it up, I may have to award you some bounty for humor.

Comment: I tried adding the line to my functions.php but it seems it applies to standard posts (not custom type posts). Also I do not want this filter to apply to every post. Preferably just the custom field. So this is really not an option here.

Comment: `the_field()` doesn't actually have the third `$format_value` parameter...but [`get_field() does`](https://github.com/elliotcondon/acf/blob/e8fef3a78248cff2b61b419964652177311325cb/core/api.php#L186)

Comment: Using a URL field type seems to make more sense.  Only other use case may be the ability to add in the embed code with the link, in which case text area would be best bet.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the WYSIWYG is adding those `<p>` tags, due to WordPress's `wpautop` function.

Rather than completely disabling `wpautop`, you could remove the `<p>` tags using a combination of `get_field()` and [`wp_strip_all_tags()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_strip_all_tags):

```
echo wp_strip_all_tags( get_field('field_name'), true );
```

EDIT: On second thought, why are you using a WYSIWYG for this at all? If you're just pasting a link, you should consider using a `text` field, or a `url` field.

Comment: Good call on the ACF.  I had missed that they were using that.

Comment: Why am I using WYSIWYG? Good question. The answer is because it is the only way the ACF plugin will let wordpress automatically embed media automatically. More info here: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/oembed/
As to the method you are suggesting I have not been successful. I placed the code inside content.php
Here is a copy of content.php http://pasted.co/ced4e2a9
Please have a look through and check if I have applied it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I did not have access to the code, nor I had access to any plugins, hence I tried this only using the WYSIWYG editor.

To remove the any unwanted paragraphs from any particular web element like div just follow these steps:

1. add a class to your div (the div which is containing that unwanted paragraphs).
2. Write a javascript function using querySelectorAll.

Example Below:

```js
var blankps=document.querySelectorAll('.removePara p');for(var i=0;i<blankps.length;i++){blankps[i].remove();}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 removePara">
<p></p>
How to Remove Empty Paragraphs. Solved.
<p></p>
</div>
```

Note: This will remove all the paragraphs inside any div which has class="removePara".

Hope this helps someone.