# WordPress plugin output contains extra tags

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have a WP plugin, some of my users have an issue on frontend. The plugin shortcode output includes additional tags: p, code and etc. But this tags not my, something added them to my content, as result the plugin doesn't work correctly. And I can't find the reason, because this users have a lot of active plugins.
Near is my code for shortcode output.

```php
public function shortcode( $atts ) {
...
ob_start();
...
$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
return $output;
}
```

**Additional note:**

I found the problem, it's a **wpautop** filter, but I do not understand how to disable it temporary, only for my part of code.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248628/disable-wordpress-from-adding-p-tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

in your functions.php