# Why can't I reuse the code for my 'read now' button?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a piece of code that creates a 'read more' tag in a wordpress page. It works well on one page, but if I try and duplicate it onto another page it doesn't work on the second page.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" />
<label for="mycheckbox" class="showmore">Toggle more</label>
<div class="moretext" >Some more text</div>

#mycheckbox:checked ~ .moretext {
  display: block;
}

.moretext{
  display: none;
}

#mycheckbox{
  display: none;
}
.showmore{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

I thought maybe I needed to name each one uniquely so I did the below, but the button doesn't do anything.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox1" />
<label for="mycheckbox1" class="showmore">Toggle more</label>
<div class="moretext" >Some more text</div>

#mycheckbox1:checked ~ .moretext {
  display: block;
}

.moretext{
  display: none;
}

#mycheckbox1{
  display: none;
}
.showmore{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Can someone please tell me what i'm doing wrong. Thanks

*************UPDATE*****************

```
This is the entire HTML portion of the code

<H3> Send Chrysanthemums all over Cape Town and Surrounds</H3>
<div class = "textcontainer">

The history of chrysanthemums dates back to China in the 15th century. Chrysanthemum flowers offered such perfection with the beautiful alignment of petals that it quickly became the blossom of nobility in ancient China. It was held in such high esteem that only nobles were permitted to grow it. In this time, the chrysanthemum meaning came to include vitality and longevity. "I don't have a particular preference for chrysanthemum, yet there are indeed no better looking flowers after it blooms," wrote the Tang Dynasty (618-907) poet Yuan Zhen in his poem "Chrysanthemum."

<input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox">
 <br>
 <label for="mycheckbox" class="showmore">Toggle more</label>

 <div class="moretext">

After making its way over to Japan by Buddhist monks in 400 AD, the Japanese were so enamoured by this beautiful flower that it was soon adopted as the emperor’s crest and official seal. “Kiku” is the Japanese name for chrysanthemum and every year there is a National Chrysanthemum Day which is also referred to as the Festival of Happiness. Though it is originally a golden yellow colour, today there are thousands of different types and colours in the world that naturally have their meaning.
<br>
<br>
Our bouquets of chrysanthemums are hand wrapped and presented in our signature kraft paper and cellophane, accompanied with a beautiful card containing your personal message. These flower bouquets are sure to bring a smile to someone’s face. Select from five different bouquet size options for door to door delivery all over Cape Town and surrounding areas.
</div>
</div>
```

and the css that's going with it, is -

```
.moretext{
  display: none;
}
#mycheckbox:checked ~ .moretext {
  display: block;
}
#mycheckbox{
  display: none;
}
.showmore{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Nothing is wrong with this code. It works fine. So without any more context or code it is not possible to troubleshoot.

Comment: Maybe try using a class to call that button instead of id's since they are unique. Are there any JS errors happening?

Comment: It seems it works on a wordpress page - https://flowersforeveryone.co.za/send-tulips/ but not a category page - https://flowersforeveryone.co.za/product-category/chrysanthemums/... i'm not sure why?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work fine.  What's the problem?

```css
#mycheckbox:checked ~ .moretext {
  display: block;
}

.moretext{
  display: none;
}

#mycheckbox{
  display: none;
}
.showmore{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" />
<label for="mycheckbox" class="showmore">Toggle more</label>
<div class="moretext" >Some more text</div>
```

Comment: It seems it works on a wordpress page - https://flowersforeveryone.co.za/send-tulips/ but not a category page - https://flowersforeveryone.co.za/product-category/chrysanthemums/... i'm not sure why?

Answer (score 0):

you should define .moretext class before #mycheckbox:checked ~ .moretext (before sibling selector)

```
.moretext{
  display: none;
}
#mycheckbox:checked ~ .moretext {
  display: block;
}
#mycheckbox{
  display: none;
}
.showmore{
  cursor: pointer;
```

works on my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Hfwthorn/2rf3gtvy/2/)

**Edited:**
That's your code from not-working-page:

```
<p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox">
    <br>
    <label for="mycheckbox" class="showmore">Toggle more</label>
</p>
<div class="moretext"></div>
```

.moretext here is a sibling of < p > tag, not your input, that's why your css sibling selector doesn't work. Try to get rid of the paragraph wrapping. It should look like this(like on the working page):

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox">
 <br>
 <label for="mycheckbox" class="showmore">Toggle more</label>

 <div class="moretext"></div>
```

Wordpress automatically changes double line-breaks in the text into HTML paragraphs. This question may help: [Disable WordPress from adding <p> tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248628/disable-wordpress-from-adding-p-tags)

Comment: I've copied your code but I can't get it to work - https://flowersforeveryone.co.za/product-category/chrysanthemums/ am i doing something wrong?

Comment: It does work on this page though - https://flowersforeveryone.co.za/send-tulips/ why would that be?? Thanks

Comment: wordpress can be a little confusing with it's css.  Are you identifying the class that covers the entire page?

Comment: @ Michelle, I've edited my answer after looking into your pages. If you'll have problems with finding why wp adds this <p> tag, please, tell how exactly you add this piece of code into your page(from dashboard or from php?)

Comment: Hi.. I've added the entire piece of HTML code above, under the heading UPDATE. I am adding this into the woocommerce product > categories page editor.. and the css is going into the css customiser. Thanks

Comment: ok, I see 2 options: 1) use the code from the link to disable the wpautop filter which changes your double linebreaks <br><br> into paragraph 2) minify your code: when you're adding html code in the editor - remove all white spaces, so it looks like a string: <div class = "textcontainer">text1<input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox"><br><label for="mycheckbox" class="showmore">Toggle more</label><div class="moretext">text2<br>text3</div></div>